# Set focus on jquery tools overlay

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I set the focus to jquery tools overlay after it's been loaded? I've tried using `.focus()` on a link that's in the overlay but I don't like that it's highlighted. So I tried to use `.blur()` after focus() but that doesn't work.

I also tried using `tabindex` on an `h1` but it has the same problem of being highlighted.

I want to set the focus on my overlay so that users can press 'space' to scroll down the page within the overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem with the focused link is that it is highlighted with a the dotted outline, that can be fixed like:

```
a {
    outline: 0;
}
```

You can read about this here: http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/